# streetview images fail to load in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox, google-street-view

I've got a page with Google streetview running in a tab. It's failing to work properly in Firefox (Linux and Windows).

The streetview code loads properly-- you can see all the map controls, and there's no js errors reported. In firebug's network panel you can even see the images for the streetview (tiles I guess) loading.

However, the viewport just shows a grey block, with the streetview controls superimposed on it.

Streetview works properly in Google Chrome on the same page, same machine. I've also tested from a Win 7 machine, and see the same problem in FF, while it works properly in IE and Chrome.

The same code works perfectly in Firefox on the same Linux machine on another site I've got locally, and streetview performs as designed, so I don't think it's the Flash plugin, as many posts on various forums suggest.

Any ideas on this?

Here's the link:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The page generate below css directly.
So, get rid this css.

Line at 415:

```
img {
  height:auto !important;
 //max-width:100% !important;   // <- remove this css
  ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: which css file are you seeing this in?

Comment: thanks-- can you please explain what's happening and why this is affecting the streetview?

Comment: Someone give this person a hug, cause I owe him one :D